# MailTrap not working on Laravel with homestead

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-5.6

I used to use MailTrap with Laravel just fine.

However, since I updated to Laravel 5.6 and updated to Homestead, I can't seem to send any mail using MailTrap.

Here is a snippet of how my `.env` file looks similar to:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@foo.com
```

I have also cleared my config cache and re-cached it, as well as restarted the server.

Whenever, I try sending mail I get a `Swift_TransportException` with the message: `Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [Connection timed out #110]`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue.

Comment: From the homestead try to run `telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 2525`

Comment: Can you ping mailtrap.io from the homestead box? Sounds like a networking issue to me.

Comment: Instead of `MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io` use `MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io`.

Comment: @Troyer It Worked! Thanks so much. Did they change this or something, as it used to work fine. PLease put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io` to `MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io` because `mailtrap.io` is a deprecated url.

You can read more [there](https://mailtrap.io/blog/2018-03-09-why-mailtrap-updated-its-smtp-host).

> On 8 March 2018 Mailtrap blocked the traffic from “mailtrap.io”.
>
> The Mailtrap users who signed up for Mailtrap before November 10th,
> 2016 and did not update their credentials **have to** make a slight change
> in the SMTP host address: **add “smtp” to the current SMTP host name**.
> So, instead of “mailtrap.io”, it will be called “smtp.mailtrap.io”